# Compiled List of Elasticity Constants

Tags: resource-recommendations, elasticity

I'm wondering if there is a compiled list of elasticity constants for anisotropic materials somewhere. I am running numerical experiments for a variety of different symmetry types (trinclinic, monoclinic, orthotropic, etc). I've been searching manually through papers to obtain the constants; however, for monoclinic symmetries like gypsum I have been having quite a bit of trouble finding data giving all thirteen constants. I'm just curious if there is a compiled list for a variety of materials in some location.

Comment: Perhaps you could start making the list! But, more seriously, I don't know even of many such systems where the elastic constants have been measured particularly well in the first place.

Comment: May try Kaye and Laby (http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_2/2_2_2.html), give for isotropic materials and the references may help?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why such a list would not be very useful in "real world" engineering: unless you can control the orientation of the crystals in the material, you can't make much practical use of the data.

If the crystals are small and randomly oriented, the bulk material properties will be approximately isotropic.

This kind of data is certainly measured for specialist applications like single-crystal turbine blades in jet engines, where not only is the crystal orientation of the material closely controlled, but different blades in the same turbine may intentionally have different crystal orientations, to avoid resonances caused by all the blades having very similar vibration frequencies. But of course those material properties are not in the public domain.